# How to alias a macro in julia

Tags: macros, julia

I'd like to make a name alias of a macro. My current implementation is to create a new macro that call and pass over the argument, eg.:

```
macro print(xs...)
  quote
    @show $(xs...)
  end
end
```

Is there any better / built-in way to this?

Comment: Great question!  I had the very same one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also do:

```
julia> @eval const $(Symbol("@print")) = $(Symbol("@show"))
@show (macro with 1 method)

julia> @print 1 + 1
1 + 1 = 2
2
```

Comment: Thanks for showing 2 ways to get a reference to a macro. I could not see these in  https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming

Comment: You should not assume things are available in `Main`, the binding should probably also be made `const`. Something like `@eval const $(Symbol("@print")) = $(Symbol("@show"))` is much simpler, and does not assume that the macro is available in `Main` -- it is enough that it is available in the scope of the assignment.

Comment: @fredrikekre thanks, much better! I only knew about doing it with getfield because TotalVerb, once showed me that, that is what the expression is expanded and lowered to.

Comment: @fredrikekre Great answer to the same question I had.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In Julia 1.3, you can use the `var"@macroname"` syntax, like so:

```
var"@print" = var"@show"
```

Then, `@show` will be effectively aliased to `@print`.

Comment: Should probably be `const` as well: `const var"@print" = var"@show"`.